# What does Cmd+Up/Down do on mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

I'm curious in what Cmd+Up/Down does in the default mac terminal app. When I press the combination, it shows a yellow box around the previous command but doesn't actually select it.

What are some actual use cases of this shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They function as *Mark* shortcuts. Simply put, they allow you to navigate from prompt line to prompt line, skipping large output, for example. Other functionalities include bookmarking of lines to which you may want to come back.

Check the *Edit » Mark* menu: you'll find more options.

[This answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209907/611) explains it better than I could, so head there for more info.